# GUI buttons, getting response in the app window instead of command line

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am needing to have the following buttons of my code/GUI program produce the output to the app window itself rather than my VS code command line and having a bit of a mental block on this. Right now when each button is clicked, the program runs just fine but the output is in the wrong place. Am i missing something?

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    tk = tkinter.Tk()   
    

    frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=100)

    label = tkinter.Label(frame, text=" insert response box here ")
    label.pack(fill=X, expand=100)
    
    button1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Network Device Scan", command=test_log)
    button1.pack(side=LEFT)
    button2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="connect keypad", command=raspi_connecter)
    button2.pack(side=LEFT)
    button3 = tkinter.Button(frame, text= "run tests", command= keypad_tests)
    button3.pack(side=LEFT)
    button4 = tkinter.Button(frame, text= "serial_ssh", command= serial_ssh )
    button4.pack(side=LEFT)

    tk.mainloop()
```

If more of my code is needed for clarification please lmk.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just need to know how to get my outputs of the functions "test_log", "keypad_tests" to show in the app window instead of the command line in VS code

Comment: It's difficult to say as you have not presented the relevant code. The use of `if __name__=='__main__':` suggests that you are building an object-oriented application. In that case you should create the buttons and callback functions within the main class. If you want more help you should post relevant code as described in my first comment.